# Mimic spyder sort column

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I had a quick question: I am using Spyder, and a neat feature is in the variable explorer tab, I am able to click the headers and sort columns. However I am unable to reproduce the same sort order when I try to use:

```
df.sort_values()
```

in python. I'm wondering if there is any way to reproduce the order of a Spyder sort, in python code.

Answer (score 0):

if you just use `df.sort_values()` it will not work indeed.

Using `df.sort_values(COLUMN_NAMESTRING)` with optional keyword `ascending=False` for reverse ordering, will work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give the same results either. I'm interested to see how Spyder sorts vs Python sorts

Comment: Then please give a verifiable example, as for my dataframe I am testing (some ohlc data), it works exactly the same..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to to specify the new data frame variable for example:

```
df=df.sort_values([column])
```